# Post/Redirect/Get pattern in flask

Tags: python, redirect, flask, flask-wtforms, post-redirect-get

The view function of my toy app was:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=name)
```

And it looks like this when I use PRG:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'))
```

As you can see, the `form.name.data = ''` line is used to clear the input field in the first version, but it's not needed in the second version. I thought Flask-WTF would automatically pass the text in `StringField` into the new `form` instance, but for some reasons, it didn't.

My question is: Why `form.name.data` is no longer available between different requests when I use PRG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't pass anything on a redirect, as it is a completely new request.

Comment: Do you imply that, in the first version, when I press the submit button, the "old" request is sent again?

Comment: The current request completes, and sends the response. But a redirect is an instruction to the browser to request a new page, which means a new request and a new invocation of the handler.

Comment: Gotcha, but in the first version, isn't a "completely new request" sent each time a user click the submit button? Or in other words, do you mean that in the first version, the `index` handler is actually invoked only once?

Comment: Well if you want to put it like that, the original GET is one request, and the POST is a second request. In your original code, the response is rendered on that same request as the POST, so it includes the context from there. But in the second code, the POST request returns a redirect, which causes the browser to make a *third* request; this now has none of the context from the POST.